# Error message while executing solidity contract

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, remix

I am learning solidity. The code i have written compiles correctly and the same solution is given in the solutions of the question but it keeps reverting without any output. Please check the code once and let me know the mistake.

The question is to transfer the given amount from the amount array to the to array from the same position, i.e., from ith position of amount to ith position of to.

It shows the error message : "The transaction has been reverted to the initial state.
Note: The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance."

```
    //SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity >=0.5.0 <0.9.0;

contract Day4 {
    address owner;

    constructor() {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    function send(address payable[] memory to, uint256[] memory amount)
        public
        payable
        ownerOnly
    {
        require(to.length == amount.length, "to must be same length as amount");
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < to.length; i++) {
            to[i].transfer(amount[i]); //to array  - 0x00 0x01 0x02
            //amount array - 10 20 30
        }
    }

    modifier ownerOnly() {
        require(msg.sender == owner,"You are not the owner");
        _;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue depends from `transfer()` function. In details, this function allow you to transfer a specific amount from the smart contract balance to another address.

In your case, when you call directly `send()` function the smart contract balance is 0 because I think (since I don't see a deposit method) that you didn't deposit an amount to it.

For this reason, when you call `send()` function it reverts and doesn't works.

To solve this issue before call `send()` method, try to deposit a specific amount of ether to smart contract and then call `send()` method.

***REMEMBER***: The sum of array amount must be less to smart contract balance, otherwise it reverts.

I adjusted your smart contract in this way:

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity >=0.5.0 <0.9.0;

contract Day4 {
    address owner;

    constructor() {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    function send(address payable[] memory to, uint256[] memory amount)
        public
        payable
        ownerOnly
    {
        require(to.length == amount.length, "to must be same length as amount");
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < to.length; i++) {
            to[i].transfer(amount[i]);
        }
    }

    modifier ownerOnly() {
        require(msg.sender == owner,"You are not the owner");
        _;
    }

    // NOTE: Call this function for first, and before this operation set the values inside msg.value textbox in 
    //       Remix IDE (if you're using it) 
    function deposit() public payable {

    }
}
```